# Find the first character that is not whitespace in a std::string

Tags: c++, string, stl

Lets say I have

```
std::wstring str(L"   abc");
```

The contents of the string could be arbitrary.

How can I find the first character that is not whitespace in that string, i.e. in this case the position of the 'a'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it (C++03 compatible, in C++11 you can use a lambda):

```
#include <cwctype>
#include <functional>

typedef int(*Pred)(std::wint_t);
std::string::iterator it =
    std::find_if( str.begin(), str.end(), std::not1<Pred>(std::iswspace) );
```

It returns an iterator, subtract `str.begin()` from it if you want an index (or use `std::distance`).

Answer (score 6):

use [`std::basic_string::find_first_not_of][1]` function

```
std::wstring::size_type pos = str.find_first_not_of(' ');
```

pos is `3`

Update: to find any other chars

```
const wstring delims(L" \t,.;");
std::wstring::size_type pos = str.find_first_not_of(delims);
```

Comment: Does that work on all whitespace characters like '\n'?

Comment: @Christian yes, find_first_not_of has a few overloads. see my update, hope it helps