# will `str.find_first_of("\t\n\v\f\r ")` work on unix?

Tags: c++, string

I am using this `str.find_first_of("\t\n\v\f\r ")` command to find the first space, tab, end of line etc.

On my Windows computer this command works as I intended. But I am not sure if it works on a Unix OS.

Does someome know to verify my concerns, or maybe has a better way to find the first space, ext.

Comment: You can use `std::iswspace`, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658597/find-the-first-character-that-is-not-whitespace-in-a-stdstring

Comment: Why wouldn't it work on Unix?

Comment: I see nothing in that code that should not work on a Unix-like OS.

Comment: @vll `iswspace` is the `whcar_t` version, `isspace` for plain `char`.

Comment: @tomer Why do you think the `find_first_of` call you show will not work? Doesn't it seem to work in your code with some input? Then please ask about the *real* problem instead. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly please learn how to [edit] your question, for example to include a [mcve] of the problematic code (and the input, as well as expected *and* actual output).

Comment: And if the doubts you have is because of the end-of-line differences between Windows and POSIX systems, then note that in Windows the end-of-line sequence `\r\n` is translated into a single `\n`, which is the standard end-of-line character on POSIX systems. As long as the input is read as plain text, you shouldn't really see `\r\n` anywhere, it's all `\n`.

Comment: There is a solution to your worries -> test it